# In Angular, I need to search objects in an array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In Angular, I have in scope a object which returns lots of objects. Each has an ID (this is stored in a flat file so no DB, and I seem to not be able to user `ng-resource`)

In my controller:

```
$scope.fish = [
    {category:'freshwater', id:'1', name: 'trout', more:'false'},
    {category:'freshwater', id:'2', name:'bass', more:'false'}
];
```

In my view I have additional information about the fish hidden by default with the `ng-show` more, but when I click the simple show more tab, I would like to call the function `showdetails(fish.fish_id)`. 
My function would look something like:

```
$scope.showdetails = function(fish_id) {  
    var fish = $scope.fish.get({id: fish_id});
    fish.more = true;
}
```

Now in the the view the more details shows up. However after searching through the documentation I can't figure out how to search that `fish` array.

So how do I query the array? And in console how do I call debugger so that I have the `$scope` object to play with?

Answer (score 95, accepted):

I know if that can help you a bit.

Here is something I tried to simulate for you.

Checkout the jsFiddle ;)

http://jsfiddle.net/migontech/gbW8Z/5/

Created a filter that you also can use in 'ng-repeat'

```
app.filter('getById', function() {
  return function(input, id) {
    var i=0, len=input.length;
    for (; i<len; i++) {
      if (+input[i].id == +id) {
        return input[i];
      }
    }
    return null;
  }
});
```

Usage in controller:

```
app.controller('SomeController', ['$scope', '$filter', function($scope, $filter) {
     $scope.fish = [{category:'freshwater', id:'1', name: 'trout', more:'false'},  {category:'freshwater', id:'2', name:'bass', more:'false'}]

     $scope.showdetails = function(fish_id){
         var found = $filter('getById')($scope.fish, fish_id);
         console.log(found);
         $scope.selected = JSON.stringify(found);
     }
}]);
```

If there are any questions just let me know.

Comment: As Im new to angular and javascript, I'm not getting the meaning of '+' in 
"if (+input[i].id == +id) {" statement, can you please share your thoughts.

Comment: Perfect Solution !!

Comment: I think the "+input[i].id == +id" makes sure you are comparing numbers. So you can pass 1 or '1' to the $filter and it would behave the exact same way.
I'm using alphanumeric Ids, so I changed it to "input[i].id === id"

Answer (score 211):

You can use the existing $filter service. I updated the fiddle above http://jsfiddle.net/gbW8Z/12/

```
 $scope.showdetails = function(fish_id) {
     var found = $filter('filter')($scope.fish, {id: fish_id}, true);
     if (found.length) {
         $scope.selected = JSON.stringify(found[0]);
     } else {
         $scope.selected = 'Not found';
     }
 }
```

Angular documentation is here http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter:filter

Comment: very helpful - As I learn angular I'm realizing that I need to stop thinking jQuery functions first (was trying to get $.grep to do this) - rather using this $filter service was just what I needed!

Comment: Could you add details what `$scope.selected` is / contains. Doing a quick-search on selected i found [`ng-selected` / ngSelected:](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSelected) `If the expression is truthy, then special attribute "selected" will be set on the element`. Is this the same? In your example what does it do?
Thanks

Comment: Don't forget to add the $filter service to your controller. i.e: app.controller('mainController', ['$filter', function($filter) { // $filter can now be used. }]);

Answer (score 22):

To add to @migontech's answer and also his address his comment that you could "probably make it more generic", here's a way to do it.  The below will allow you to search by any property:

```
.filter('getByProperty', function() {
    return function(propertyName, propertyValue, collection) {
        var i=0, len=collection.length;
        for (; i<len; i++) {
            if (collection[i][propertyName] == +propertyValue) {
                return collection[i];
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
});
```

The call to filter would then become:

```
var found = $filter('getByProperty')('id', fish_id, $scope.fish);
```

Note, I removed the unary(+) operator to allow for string-based matches...

Comment: considering the documentation states that this is the only use case for ng-init, I would say this is definitely the Angular way to do it.

Comment: Very easy to understand example and very helpful

Answer (score 13):

A dirty and easy solution could look like

```
$scope.showdetails = function(fish_id) {
    angular.forEach($scope.fish, function(fish, key) {
        fish.more = fish.id == fish_id;
    });
};
```

Comment: Why this is a _dirty_ solution ?

Comment: my guess would be because there may be, like, a billion fish records and we're just looping through them one by one

Comment: There'd be even more records in other languages.  I mean, there's plenty of fish in the C++.  (Oh shut up..  I'll go and vote myself down..!!)

Answer (score 7):

Angularjs already has filter option to do this , 
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter

Answer (score 7):

Your solutions are correct but unnecessary complicated. You can use **pure javascript filter function**. This is your model:

```
     $scope.fishes = [{category:'freshwater', id:'1', name: 'trout', more:'false'},  {category:'freshwater', id:'2', name:'bass', more:'false'}];
```

And this is your function:

```
     $scope.showdetails = function(fish_id){
         var found = $scope.fishes.filter({id : fish_id});
         return found;
     };
```

You can also use expression:

```
     $scope.showdetails = function(fish_id){
         var found = $scope.fishes.filter(function(fish){ return fish.id === fish_id });
         return found;
     };
```

More about this function: [LINK](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_filter.asp)

Answer (score 4):

Saw this thread but I wanted to search for IDs that did not match my search. Code to do that:

```
found = $filter('filter')($scope.fish, {id: '!fish_id'}, false);
```

Comment: This worked for me. Simple, slick, easy to test. Thanks!