# How to check if an item is already existing in an array before push using angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have three arrays:

- `arr1=["14","16","1"]` — where I am selecting
- `arr2=["14"]` — where I am comparing my selection from `arr1`
- `arr3=[]` — where I am pushing the value.

How will I be able to check if my selection does not exist in `arr2`?

For example I selected 14 from `arr1`, since it is already existing in `arr2`, the button will be disabled and should not be pushed in `arr3`.

Comment: [Search objects in Array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15610501/in-angular-i-need-to-search-objects-in-an-array)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

That is a JavaScript relating question, not AngularJS. But may that answer your question:

```
if(arr2.indexOf("14") == -1){
  arr3.push("14");
}
```

Comment: See this questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1744310/how-to-fix-array-indexof-in-javascript-for-ie-browsers

Comment: If you are using babel ES6, you can use Set and push without checking