# AngularJS getting data from item where

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

When an item in the list is clicked, an `ng-click` fires with the `id` of the item sent, the idea was to get the `description` of the item to match the `id` but it seems to only be picking up the `index` of the item instead.

[Plnk](http://plnkr.co/edit/qXrYqTw5pBOLQTturi9J?p=preview)

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  $http.get('tasks.json').success(function(data) {
               $scope.tasks = data.item;
                console.log($scope.tasks);
            });

            $scope.viewTask = function(id) {
              console.log(id);
              console.log($scope.tasks[id].description); //The Description to go with the ID.
            };
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are returning the task with index of `id`.  It sounds like you want to search the array for the task with a certain id and return that one's description.  Something like:

```
  $scope.viewTask = function(id) {
          console.log(id);
          for(i=0;i<$scope.tasks.length;i++) {
             if ($scope.tasks[i].id == id) {
                 console.log($scope.tasks[id].description);
             } 
          }

 };
```

You could create a filter or something to make this easier but the logic is the same.  There are several answers here that would help with a filter so as to not duplicate code:

[In Angular, I need to search objects in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15610501/in-angular-i-need-to-search-objects-in-an-array)

In this case your function would look l ike:

```
$scope.viewTask = function(id) {
          console.log(id);
          var found = $filter('getById')($scope.tasks, id);
          console.log(found.description);
 };
```

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/UMApcLbzz0HZIKkRrnOQ?p=preview

I modified the answer to log the data like your question.

Comment: I went for this

`var found = $filter('filter')($scope.tasks, {id: task_id}, true);
    if (found.length) { found[0].description; }`