# Understanding scope, ng-click and the angular-way

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-click

While working on the phone tutorial i wondered how to implement this use case

1. user clicks on `add phone`
2. the function `addItem` is fired and the `phone.id` is passed
3. the relevant phone is retrieved and the quantity increased by 1
4. the increased quantity should be displayed in the input

You can find my **[codepen demo here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yNEKVY)** and this is the relevant code

```
<ul class="phones">
  <li ng-repeat="phone in phones | filter:query | orderBy:orderProp">
    <b>{{phone.name}} </b>
    <i ng-click="addItem(phone.id)"> add phone</i>
    <input name='{{phone.id}}' 
           value='{{phone.qty}}' 
           ng-readonly='{{phone.orderReadonly}}' /><br />        
    <p>{{phone.snippet}} </p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

and the javascript

```
var phonecatApp = angular.module('phonecatApp', []);

phonecatApp.controller('PhoneListCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.phones = [
     {'id': 1, 'name': 'Mui 1'
             ,'snippet': 'Our newcomer from asia.' 
             ,'orderReadonly' : 'false', 'qty': 4}    
     ....
    ,{'id': 4, 'name': 'Msft Lumia™'
             ,'snippet': 'Who knows what windows 10 will bring'
             ,'orderReadonly' : 'true','qty': 2}
  ];
  $scope.orderProp = 'id';
  $scope.addItem = function(phone_id) {
     // from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15610501/
     var found = $filter('filter')($scope.phones, {id: phone_id}, true);   
     if (found.length) {
       found[0].qty = found[0].qty + 1;
     } else {
         $scope.selected = 'Not found';
     }
  }
});
```

#### Current status

- passing the id works
- finding the phone does not work: `var found = $filter('filter')($scope.phones, {id: phone_id}, true); // found in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15610501/`
- increasing quantity does not work

#### My questions are

- if and how onclick / ng-click should be used in the angular way
- how to solve my requirement - increase phone quantity onclick on `<i>add phone</i>`

Comment: Much simpler to pass whole objects rather than an id into methods

Comment: I just noticed that `var found = $filter('filter')...` returns a new array so changing its value is of little use. How do i get a reference to the phone inside the array `phones`?

Comment: what is `$filter`? it doesn't appear to be valid.  aside from that, it's not even necessary.  Just pass `phone` in to the function, and do `phone.qty++`.

Comment: Thanks @charlietfl: This seems to do the trick: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XbYEZR

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VLdXQB

Comment: Claise is right - you are not injecting `$filter` into your controller - you need to do this: `phonecatApp.controller('PhoneListCtrl', function($scope, $filter)...`. But as others have said, that isn't necessary if you pass `phone` into your click handler, instead of `phone.id`.

Comment: Thanks @Claies this seems to work. I am not sure what [filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) is i copied it from another answer.

Comment: and as was mentioned in another answer, you could even more simply just do `ng-click="phone.qty++"` and not even have a function.

Comment: @Claies just using `ng-click="phone.qty++"` did not work, but using `ng-click="phone.qty = phone.qty + 1"` did - see answer from teamnorge.

Comment: I played around some more: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bdmdqg

Comment: My next question will be about: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zGmGgV

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know why `qty` doesn't work - it should, unless your filter doesn't find a match.

But you shouldn't even be doing this. Instead of passing the `id` of the object and then locating the object to change its property, just pass the object `phone` itself:

```
<i ng-click="addItem(phone)"> add phone</i>
```

Then, in the controller, simply do this:

```
$scope.addItem = function(phone) {
  phone.qty = phone.qty + 1;
}
```

Comment: It was suggested that for this case the function `addItem` is not needed but instead use `<i ng-click="qty++">add phone</i>` or `<i ng-click="phone.qty++">add phone</i>` but [at least my attempt to use ng-click=qty++ failed](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LVrdmm). What would you recommend?

Comment: @threeFourOneSixOneThree, You would need to use `ng-click="phone.qty++"` (you need to reference the local `phone` object) and for this simple example it is fine. But as a best practice, I keep the logic away from the View (i.e. the HTML) unless it is very View-specific, which in this case, it is not.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your first question:

Using ng-click runs an angular expression inside Angular's scope.  If you use the onclick simply runs javascript code.

So if you have some variable 'numPhones' initialized inside your controller, then you can have:

```
ng-click="numPhones = numPhones + 1"
```

and the numPhones variable will be incremented.

On the other hand:

```
onclick="numPhones = numPhones + 1"
```

doesn't reference the surrounding angular scope.

So if you're using Angular, you probably wouldn't want onclick at all.

Here's an example:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        angular.module('phones', [])
    </script>
</head>
<body ng-app='phones'>
    <div>
        {{ numPhones }}
        <button ng-click="numPhones = numPhones + 1"> add 1</button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: normally would get values like numphones from array lengths

Comment: yeah I was just trying to get at the difference between using onclick and ng-click

Comment: Would `ng-click="numPhones++;"` increase the property numPhones on the current object?

Comment: It would add one to the variable numPhones in the current scope--so in the surrounding controller (in most cases).  Is that what you mean by 'on the current object'?

Comment: I [forked the codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LVrdmm) to show how i understood your answer, i tried `phone.qty++` and `qty++` but both did not work for me.

Comment: so I tried to run it, and I think you actually can't use "++" and have to do "qty = qty + 1" for whatever reason.

Answer (score 1):

Summarising the two above answers. The `"++"` increment will not work on the variable or object property from the `"ng-click"` directive, so instead you should use:

```
variable = variable + 1
```

And in connection to the original question the

```
<i ng-click="phone.qty = phone.qty + 1"> add phone</i>
```

will do the trick.