# Adding item to model and refresh a second ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

While working on the phone tutorial i wondered how to implement this use case

1. browser renders a list of phones
2. user clicks on `add phone` for one of these phones
3. the function `addItem` is fired and adds this phone into the array phonesInCart
4. the list with phones in cart `$scope.phonesInCart = [];` is updated

My **[codepen demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GJYjoY)** has the same logic as this code

```
<body ng-controller="PhoneListCtrl">
<h3>Phones we sell</h3>
<ul class="phones">
  <li ng-repeat="phone in phones | filter:query | orderBy:orderProp">
    <b>{{phone.name}} </b>
    <button ng-click="addItem(phone)"
            ng-disabled="{{phone.orderReadonly}}">add phone</button>
  </li>
</ul>

<h3>Phones in your cart</h3>
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="phoneInCart in phonesInCart"> 
    {{phoneInCart.name}}
  </li> 
</ul>
</body>
```

and relevant javascript

```
$scope.phonesInCart = [];
$scope.addItem = function(phone) { 
    // these lines have no effect on the ui
    phonesInCart.push(phone);
    $scope.$apply();
}
```

#### Current status

The list is rendered and the 'addItem' function is fired.
Currently the list of the phones in cart are not updated / not rendered.

#### My question

Could you explain

- what has to be done to fill a second array `phonesInCart[]` and refresh another `ng-repeat` and
- do i have to create / use more than one controller `phonecatApp.controller('PhoneListCtrl' ...` to be able to have a secon `ng-repeat`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, instead of `phonesInCart.push(phone)`, you need to do:

```
$scope.phonesInCart.push(phone)
```

Since that is the variable you loop over in your html.

**EDIT** Since the `addItem` call happens as a part of an `ng-click` directive, you can get rid of `$scope.$apply`. Actually, you should be getting an error saying 'digest loop already in progress' with your current code.

Comment: I added your line `$scope.phonesInCart.push(phone)` inside `$scope.addItem = function(phone) { ...` and removed ` $scope.$apply();` and it seems to work: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PqyGXY

Comment: Great! Do note that any thing that happens as a response to an angular action, like an ajax request callback (when using $http), or an ng-click handler, or ng-mouseover, etc. is always executed inside a $scope.$apply(..), so you don't need to call it yourself. If you do, (and you can see this in your web console) you will see angular throw an error.

Comment: If a a button is clicked multiple times (to increase the number of phones) angular reports `Error: [ngRepeat:dupes]`. [This answer contains a way to filter an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15610501) but writing `phonecatApp.filter('getById', function() {` [did not work for me](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QbZpXK). Could you help me how do i check if a phone is already in the array `phonesInCart`?

Answer (score 1):

I edited your codepen code slightly.

- First off, as others already pointed out, you missed a `$scope` when pushing into the array of phones.
- Secondly, if you want to be able to add multiple of the same phones to the list, you need to add `track by $index` to your ng-repeat, so it accepts "duplicates".
- You also had an unnecessary `$scope.apply` in your addPhone function - you don't need to update it manually; when you push to the scope variable array, it triggers the digest cycle itself.
- Lastly, you don't need to `$watch` the phonesInCart array due to the same reason as above.

[Here's an updated pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zGmKMp) to which all these changes have been made. If you have anything else to ask, please do :)

Comment: I see  `<li ng-repeat="phoneInCart in phonesInCart track by $index">` cause that the same phone can be added multiple times into the array `phonesInCart`. My prefered option would be to increase the qty of a certain phone.