# Unknown Provider Error when using $filter service

Tags: angularjs, filter, ionic-framework, runtime-error

I'm creating a hybrid app using the Ionic framework, and I set up a factory to hold an array of objects. I wanted to use the $filter service to grab an object within the array that has a certain ID. This is the code I have right now. I got the idea for this implementation from this stack overflow question: [In Angular, I need to search objects in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15610501/in-angular-i-need-to-search-objects-in-an-array).

```
angular.module('prototype.services', [])

.factory('Patients', function($filter) {

var currentID;
var currentPatient = $filter('patientFilter')(patients, {id: currentID}, true);


var patients = [{
id: 1,
name: 'Alexander Hamilton'
}];



return {

all:function() {
    return patients;
},

add: function(patient) {
    patients.push( {
        name: patient.name
    })
},

setID: function(id) {
    currentID = id;
},

getID: function() {
    return currentID;    
},


};



});
```

From what I understand, this should work since I injected $filter into the factory I created. I'm pretty new to angular so there may be something obvious that I'm missing.

Full error was :

```
ionic.bundle.js:26794 Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider:     patientFilterFilterProvider <- patientFilterFilter <- Patients
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.3/$injector/unpr?    p0=patientFilterFilterProvider%20%3C-%20patientFilterFilter%20%3C-%20Patients
at ionic.bundle.js:13438
at ionic.bundle.js:17788
at Object.getService [as get] (ionic.bundle.js:17941)
at ionic.bundle.js:17793
at Object.getService [as get] (ionic.bundle.js:17941)
at ionic.bundle.js:32697
at Object.<anonymous> (services.js:6)
at Object.invoke (ionic.bundle.js:17995)
at Object.enforcedReturnValue [as $get] (ionic.bundle.js:17834)
at Object.invoke (ionic.bundle.js:17995)
```

Comment: Are you minifying your code?

Comment: @SteamDev  I don't believe I am, and I don't have a lot of experience with angular or ionic to see if I am. However, I did change the factory statement to 

    .factory('Patients' , ['$filter', function($filter) { 

just in case, and I was still getting the error.

Comment: Can you include the code where the patientFilter is being defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is assuming there is a `patientFilter` attached to your module:

```
angular.module('prototype.services', [])

.filter('patientFilter', function(){/*...*/}) // doesn't exist, so unknown provider errors
```

What you probably want to do is the following...

```
angular.module('prototype.services', [])

.factory('Patients', function($filter) {

    var currentID;
    var patients = [{
        id: 1,
        name: 'Alexander Hamilton'
    }];

    return {

      // ... other factory methods ...

      getCurrentPatient: function(){
        var currentPatient = $filter('filter')(patients, { // use generic 'filter' filter
            id: currentID
        }, true);

        return currentPatient || patients[0];
      }
    }
});
```

Comment: This fixed the error! Thank you for explaining it all to me. If you don't mind could you explain why you returned currentPatient || patients[0] instead of just currentPatient? Wouldn't currentPatient hold the object that "passed" the filter?

Comment: There is a chance that `currentPatient` can be null or undefined if `currentID` hasn't been set yet, or if `currentID` doesn't match any of the items in your array. Just a safety net in case `currentPatient` is a falsey value.